# Picasso loads 6 images only from cache

Tags: android, image, picasso

For some reason, Picasso is displaying only 6 images out of 20. It shows the first 6 images and then repeats them. I am getting the images from the web.

Any idea?

```
Picasso.get().load(response.body().getMediaDetails()
.getSizes().getFull().getSourceUrl())
.fetch(new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {}

  @Override
  public void onError(Exception e) {

    // Try again online if cache failed
    Picasso.get()
   .load(response.body().getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFull().getSourceUrl())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.test_img_size)
    .error(R.drawable.test_img_size)
    .into(imageView);

  }
});
```

**ViewAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Model> dataset;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Model> list;
private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public static List<WPPost> mListPost;
ArrayList<String> imagepath = new ArrayList<>();
private String baseURL = "https://www.myfitbytes.com/";

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Model> mlist, Context context) {
    this.dataset = mlist;
    this.mContext = context;
}

public static class ImageTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    TextView title, subtitle, date;
    ImageView imageView;
    CardView cardview;

    public ImageTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.title = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      //this.subtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        this.date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Icon);
        this.cardview = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.postdetails, parent, false);





    return new ImageTypeViewHolder(view) ;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Model object = dataset.get(position);
   // Log.d("RecyclerViewAdapter", "IMAGE="+object.Image);
    imagepath.add(position, "");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
    {
        //( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).subtitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(object.subtitle , Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setText( Html.fromHtml(object.title , Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY) );
        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).date.setText( Html.fromHtml(object.date , Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY) );
    }
    else
    {
        //( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).subtitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(object.subtitle ));
        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setText( Html.fromHtml(object.title ));
        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).date.setText( Html.fromHtml(object.date ));
    }


      ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, WPPostDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("itemPosition", position);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



    try {
        getthumbnail(object.Image, ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).imageView, position);



    }catch (Exception e){
     //   Log.e("adapter ","failed to get image "+e.toString() );
    }
    /// dataset.get(position)



}


public void getthumbnail(String imageurl, final ImageView imageView, final int position){

    ServiceWrapper serviceWrapper = new ServiceWrapper(null);
    Call<GetThumbnail> call = serviceWrapper.getThumbnailCall(imageurl);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<GetThumbnail>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetThumbnail> call, final Response<GetThumbnail> response) {
            if (response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {

                    if (response.body().getMediaDetails()!=null){

                       // Log.e("recycler adapter", " image is here--  " + response.body().getMediaDetails().getSizes().getThumbnail().getSourceUrl());
                       // Log.e("Full IMG SIZE - ", " THIS IS FULL IMAGE URL--  " + response.body().getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFull().getSourceUrl());

                        imagepath.add(position, response.body().getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFull().getSourceUrl());


                        Picasso.get()
                                .load(response.body().getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFull().getSourceUrl())
                                .fetch(new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess() {


                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Exception e) {

                                        // Try again online if cache failed
                                        Picasso.get()
                                                .load(response.body().getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFull().getSourceUrl())
                                                .placeholder(R.drawable.test_img_size)
                                                .error(R.drawable.test_img_size)
                                                .into(imageView);

                                    }
                                });


//Glide.with(mContext)                                    
//.load(response.body().getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFull().getSourceUrl())
//.downloadOnly(new SimpleTarget<File>() {
//@Override
//public void onResourceReady(File resource, GlideAnimation<? super File> 
//glideAnimation) {
//Glide.with(mContext)

//.load(response.body().getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFull().getSourceUrl())                                                    
//.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
 //.into(imageView);
 //}
 //});


                    }else {

                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                   // Log.e("adapter", "fail not media tag "+ e.toString());
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetThumbnail> call, Throwable t) {

          //  Log.e("adapter", " faile  image "+t.toString());
        }
    });

}




@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return dataset.size() ;
  }
 }
```

So, as some suggest and as you may see, I tried to use glade but it didn't work.
The problem is the same, when the user scrolls up and down the images re-load over and over again. And, some time it only cache 6 images out of 20 (it should cache every image in this way the app will show the image that are in the cache and not fetching in from the web)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is cache try use the methods *skipMemoryCache()* and *memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)*.

Comment: well..need them to cache tho, because if they don't cache then it will be slow next time the user open the app

Comment: The problem also is that if I dont cache the image, every time the user scrolls up and down the app try to fetch the image again and again..and make the app slow...any solution? even if I have to use Glide

Comment: Please, post your code of the RecyclerView or Listview for a better view of the problem...

Comment: Please test inserting the code on the method onError inside method onSuccess.